# d3.selectAll by classname in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, selectall

Faced with the next problem

Code

```
d3.selectAll(".edit").on...
```

Doesn't work in Chrome, but perfectly works in Firefox. `.edit` is class of some TD elements.
Why Chrome can not handle `selectall` by classname?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you put an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you share some code, We can try that in chrome and get back,